# Select Where Table.Value == Maximum

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have an SQL table with the following design:

```
TableSchedule:
Id
Description
ImportedDate
```

I can import a large number of items and they will all have the same ImportedDate.

How can I write a LINQ query that grabs only the entries with the most recent ImportedDate?

```
var ResultSchedule =
    from a in Db.TableSchedule
    where a.ImportedDate == (Newest?)
```

Comment: Why LINQ? This should really be handled on the db server.

Comment: @David Lively - It will be handled on the server assuming he's using an ORM with a linq provider instead of linq to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
var ResultSchedule = 
from a in Db.TableSchedule 
where a.ImportedDate == (from item in DB.TableSchedule Select item.ImportedDate).Max()
```

Comment: No.  As far as my understaning of LINQ goes, an expression tree gets created which results in only 1 DB Query.  If I'm wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Select * From Table
  Where ImportedDate  = 
     (Select max(ImportedDate) From Table)
```

If you need the latest record for each [something] like, say, for each individual customer, then make the siubquery *correlated*

```
  Select * From Table t
  Where ImportedDate  = 
     (Select max(ImportedDate) 
      From Table
      Where Customer = t.Customer)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var ResultSchedule = from a in Db.TableSchedule
                     let max = Db.TableSchedule.Max(i => i.ImportedDate)
                     where a.ImportedDate == max
                     select a;
```

Comment: Is this method considered a "better practice" than the method suggested by Vivek?

Comment: @Soo - Using `let` could come in handy if you make more comparisons with the `max` value. In that case you won't have to duplicate the longer line.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the results and order them by date:

```
var ResultsSchedule = Db.TableSchedule.
                      GroupBy(a => a.ImportedDate).
                      OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).
                      FirstOrDefault().
                      Select(g => g);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fluent syntax:

```
var ResultSchedule = 
    Db.TableSchedule.Where(
       a => a.ImportedDate.Equals(Db.TableSchedule.Max(b => b.ImportedDate))
    );
```